# Cocos2d-js EditBox zOrder not working

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-html5, cocos2d-js

I have an EditBox on my layer.

```
var ebox = new cc.EditBox(cc.p(200, 30));
ebox.setPosition(size.width / 2 - 50, size.height / 2);
ebox.setPlaceHolder("Password");
ebox.setInputFlag(cc.EDITBOX_INPUT_FLAG_PASSWORD);
ebox.setDelegate(this);
ebox.setFontColor({"r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 0});
ebox.setFontSize(20);
ebox.initWithBackgroundColor(cc.size(200, 30), {"r": 0, "g": 255, "b": 0});
ebox.init();

this.addChild(ebox, 1); //this - is a main layer
```

then I have to display some kind of overlay over the main layer

```
this.getParent().addChild(overlayLayer, 100);
```

overlayLayer - layer filled with color

The thing is that editbox stays always above the overlay. Why isn't zOrder working with EditBox??

Comment: Why don't you add it to the same layer as the box? this.addChild(overlayLayer, 100);

Comment: Michael, the same. I've tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem with your code. My solution is a workaround. You can use sprites as background. Then it works.

```
    var ebox = cc.EditBox.create(cc.size(170, 50), cc.Scale9Sprite.create("res/extensions/green_edit.png"), cc.Scale9Sprite.create("res/extensions/orange_edit.png"));
    ebox.setPlaceHolder("Password");
    ebox.setInputFlag(cc.EDITBOX_INPUT_FLAG_PASSWORD);
    ebox.setPosition(cc.p(size.width/2,size.height/2));
    ebox.setFontColor({"r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 0});
    ebox.setDelegate(this);
    this.addChild(ebox,1);
```